# Combine file transfer dialogs

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-8

I am considering upgrading my work computer to use windows 8 as the new file transferring feature seems very useful. Unfortunately after installing windows 8 on my home pc to test it out, the files are being transferred in separate dialogs as opposed to this [image](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-29-43-metablogapi/8156.Figure_2D00_4_2D002D002D00_Pause_2D00_more_2D00_details_2D00_view_5F00_thumb_5F00_5DB6E11C.png) provided by microsoft.

As I am transferring files constantly a single transfer dialog would make things much less confusing. Does anyone know what settings to change to make file transfers appear in the same window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make file transfers appear in the same window you need to transfer files locally.

This is because a network connection can break out at anytime.

Comment: Ah thank you. I don't really transfer files locally so this would have annoyed me to no end.